# How to concatenate a lambda expression using a for loop?

Tags: c#, lambda, expression, azure-cosmosdb

I have a documentDb database where I store some names as the ID. Now, I would like to get the items from the documentDB using those names.

For instance

```
foreach(var name in stringList){   //stringList is a list of strings
     this.mydocumentDb.getDocuments(e=>e.Id == name);
}
```

However, this will take a while since I have lots of names. Therefore, I would like to concat the names in the lambda expression if possible.

For example,

```
foreach(var name in stringlist){
    // if there is more names in the list 
    expression  + "|| e.id == "name";
}
this.mydocumentDb.getDocuments(expression);
```

Is that a possible solution, since it will increase my efficiency? If it is not possible, I have no choice but to go through every loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
this.mydocumentDb.getDocuments(e=> stringlist.Contains(e.Id));
```